# SQL: select rows which are unique on specific columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of questions pairs with the scheme of

```
id1     question1    id2    question2
1123    q1           2      q2
1123    q1           3      q3
1123    q1           1231   q142
2431    q12          1231   q142
```

( ids are not incremental and can be considered random)

I want to select tuples which are unique in both of id1 and id2, for example for the above example a desired output might be:

```
id1     question1    id2    question2
1123    q1           2      q2
2431    q12          1231   q142
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: Your desired output doesn't match the description. Why isn't `id1=1123, id2=3` in the output? It's also a unique combination.

Comment: because id1=1123 is currently appeared. the problem is that I don't know how to use "distinct" for two columns  separately.

Comment: `GROUP BY id1, id2`

Comment: Is there some data missing from your example? All your rows are unique in both of `id1` and `id2`.

Comment: Either that, or you haven't described the uniqueness criteria clearly. Why should `1123, 2` be included in the result, but not `1123, 3`?

Comment: id1 and id2 should be unique in all of the results, just one question with id 1123 can appear maybe as question1 or as question2

Comment: no matter which one appears, its important to have just one of them

Answer (score 1):

Use nested queries.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM yourTable
      GROUP BY id1) AS x
GROUP BY id2
```

However, it's unpredictable how this will do the grouping. If the subquery chooses

```
id1     id2
1123    1231
2431    1231
```

then the final result will be:

```
id1     id2
1123    1231
```

or

```
id1     id2
2431    1231
```

I'm not sure how to change it so it produces the result with the most possible combinations.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ranking as well

```
SELECT id1,
       question1,
       id2,
       question2
  FROM (SELECT CASE id1 
                    WHEN @curType 
                    THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
                    ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := id1 
                END rank,
                id1,
                question1,
                id2,
                question2
           FROM q,
                (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r
          ORDER BY  id1, id2
        ) t
 WHERE rank = 1
```

Result

```
rank id1  id2
1    1123 2
1    2431 1231
```